# Modify custom field after save_post

Tags: wordpress, post, custom-fields

In my custom post type, once the user saves the post, is there a way to check the value of one of the fields and update it? The value I will insert will depend on the post's ID so `save_post` needs to be used in case it's a new post.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood something but it sounds like the answer is in your question.

Comment: Sorry but I'm trying to learn the ropes with using `add_action`. Maybe you can post something other users like myself can work with next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can have all of your data from `$_POST` or `global $post` after you save or update the post `using save_post hook as you mentioned in your question`

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'afterSavePost' );
function afterSavePost($pid)
{
    $postId=$pid; 
    // or
    global $post;
    $postId=$post->ID;
    $postTitle=$post->post_title; 
    // or
    $postId=$_POST['ID'];
    $postTitle=$_POST['post_title']; 
}
```

You mentioned `custom field` and in that case you can use

```
$yourCustomField=get_post_meta($postId, 'your_custom_field',true); // get a custom field
```

and

```
$yourCustomField="New value";
update_post_meta($postId, 'your_custom_field', $yourCustomField); // update a custom field
```

Comment: I'm trying to get my head around using `add_action` but isn't modifying `$_POST` useless since the form has already been saved to the db?

Comment: Sorry ! didn't understand what you asked.

Comment: I'm finding `get_post_meta()` does not return submitted custom fields when first creating a post, but it does when updating a post. That's a little surprising to me, so wondered if there is a different action for handling this kind of thing when posts are first created.

Comment: [Please look ate this for more](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post).